# Update DIV coordinates on all DIVs wrapped around a DIV that is clicked and dragged on

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I am building a Google Chrome extension for my Bookmarking app.  One of the feature is the ability to select a region on the screen and generate a screenshot image to save in 1 of 4 image fields for a Bookmark record.

The animated GIF image below shows the selection process.

I have extracted the code for this part from my extension to make it work outside of the extension in a JSFiddle page here https://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/czj7gxkk/

[image]

---

Currently you can click and drag to select a region on the webpage.

I want to add the capability to drag and drop the selected region after it is generated.

The transparent grey overlay around the selection box is made up using 4 DIVs.

- Top
- Right
- Bottom
- Left

So when you click (mousedown) and drag (mousemove)  on the selection box it will need to do this:

- update coordinates for the **selectionbox**.  If you click and drag 10px to the right, it will add that 10px the selection box's CSS `left` property.
- update coordinates for the **Top overlay DIV** based on the position of the selectionarea box
- update coordinates for the **Right overlay DIV** based on the position of the selectionarea box
- update coordinates for the **Bottom overlay DIV** based on the position of the selectionarea box
- update coordinates for the **Left overlay DIV** based on the position of the selectionarea box

So as the selection box moves with drag and drop, the position of these 4 DIVs that wrap around the selection will need to have there positions updated as it all moves.

The same thing happens now as the selection box is being built but I believe it will be slightly different for **moving** the selection box as its dimensions will be a set value and not changing like it does on the creation process.

There are many Image cropping plugins which have this functionality however they get there calculations based off the image dimensions and in my case it will need to use the DOM viewport instead!

The working demo is here: https://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/czj7gxkk/

---

[image]

Comment: You don't you use one div to colour the background grey?

Comment: @davegri Yes, it seems all the "crop" style script use this method.  I guess it is so that the selection DIV in the center will not have the overlay DIV on it